What is the SSIS equivalent in Cloud/AWS tech?
Can anyone tell me how they would handle a former SQL Server process where SQL Server Integration Services - SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) | Microsoft Learn package was uploaded to a server/API?
New solution has data in is a Postgres view, Postgres is hosted in AWS. How would you schedule this to upload the view data to a REST API using AWS? This needs to be weekly. Looking for general solution direction or guide on this ETL need. Thanks!

It would appear your actual requirement is to upload data weekly to an API, rather than actually requiring SSIS -- is that correct? Are you using an Amazon RDS database? If so, I doubt that it would support a call to an external service. This seems to be related: How can I send some http request from postgresql function or trigger (but not specifically mentioning RDS). I would recommend scheduling an AWS Lambda function that extracts data from the Postgres database and then sends it to the API endpoint.

AWS glue might do what you want. It should be able to extract data from a Postgres view and then call a REST API based on that.. I'm just not sure of the level of logic that you can put in glue. This would be a complete rebuild, not a SSIS pacakge migration

Ah! It appears you can trigger an AWS Lambda function from Amazon RDS Postgres: Invoking an AWS Lambda function from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance - Amazon Relational Database Service

@JohnRotenstein would I have to worry about timeouts with lambda? It's a lot of data.

An AWS Lambda function can run for a maximum of 15 minutes.
